# Programming a Likeable Android GUI?

Tags: android, user-interface, text, graphics

I see a lot of these apps like Pulse that have really nice UIs on the android: http://cdn3.digitaltrends.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Pulse-android-625x515.jpg

I want to make a UI similar to this: http://wpuploads.appadvice.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/3030-642x481.png where the text is editable/selectable/copyable. Basically an actual textfield, which I believe Android's canvas doesn't supply. How would I create UIs like this on Android. Android's normal xml layout in my opinion usually ends up making some pretty ugly stuff, and OpenGL might be a bit too high end for this kind of job. Any suggestions.

I tried looking around the forums and couldn't find anything really similar to this question? And I am not looking for a GUI builder, but more of something to actually develop the UI. Thanks!

Comment: Hi what's the app name of the second link?

Comment: 30/30 I think... http://itunes.apple.com/no/app/id505863977

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark says, they use normal XML layout. Personally, I've never looked at it, therefore I can't be sure, but I don't see anything "special" that couldn't be done with it either.

About the second app, I think it's even simpler than Pulse, probably. However, it's heavily customized (state drawables, probably), and you'd need [`StateListDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList), a couple of [9patch graphics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) and the custom font you want to use.

If you're not familiar with customizing the appearance of controls, I suggest you start looking at those links above, and Google, of course.

**One final note:** designing a good UI is hard, let alone a custom UI where you start more or less from scratch, like those above. The Android UI provides a default look and feel that you can use... ICS being much better out of the box, but that's it (and at least it provides default tools to change that). If you can't do, or don't have the experience and/or skill, I suggest sticking to the defaults or outsourcing that job.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I realized xml can do a lot more than I originally thought.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried looking around the forums and couldn't find anything really similar to this question?

That's because you already rejected the answer. Pulse is written using "Android's normal xml layout", as are most apps on Android outside of games.